# Feign clients try to contact instances even when they are shut off

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, service-discovery

I have multiple instance of a service registered with eureka; when using FeignClient I am able to successfully contact those instances using the service name of the registered application.

But there is a "problem": if I shut down one of the instances (I have also verified that the instance has gone down correctly and it has immediately been unregistered) and then make some requests to the "gateway" that then calls the services via Feign, the load-balancer still tries for some time to contact the instance that is off, resulting in timeouts and obviously failure of the request.

How is it possible to avoid this behaviour? Is there any way to force the update of the online instances so that to avoid the timeout of the requests.

I have also tried to manually get all the online instances from the discovery-client at runtime during the application execution and the online instances list is correct (the discovery server notifies correctly about every shutdown/start of the instances almost immediately).

Why is that the FeignClient doesn't get "updated" and still calls the dead ones even if the in app discovery-client instances list has been updated?

Here you can find an example of the configuration I'm trying to use.
https://github.com/fearlessfara/feign-test

Comment: Which version are you using? Have you tried adjusting LoadBalancer cache TTL or disabling LB caching (Eureka client will do its own caching, so that's a good option)?

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek I've added the link to an example GitHub repo where you will find an exact reproduction of the "issue" I'm currently facing. Note that both with spring.cloud.loadbalancer.cache.enabled=false OR true they issue persists

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek lowering the TTL "reduces" the issue, but does not eliminate it. This mean that al least one request will fail, also I suppose that lowering the TTL invalidates more frequently the load balancer cache and I don't think that in a production environment this is a good thing to do. But please tell me if i'm talking nonsense ;)